# Show only top n records and add '...' FOR XML

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to list only a few records (say 3) and adds ... if there are more in a single line using FOR XML PATH('').

So far I have written

```
;WITH SRC AS (
    select 'A' grp, 'abc' rec
    union select 'A', 'def'
    union select 'A', 'ghi'
    union select 'A', 'jkl'
    union select 'B', 'mno'
)
SELECT (
SELECT STUFF((
SELECT TOP 3 ',' + rec FROM SRC
WHERE SRC.grp = tableA.grp
FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '') + CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM SRC WHERE SRC.grp = tableA.grp) > 3 THEN ',...' ELSE '' END
)
FROM (SELECT 'A' grp) tableA
```

The above works but I want to know if there is a way not to select from SRC twice to accomplish the job (one for the data, one for the count), because the where clause could be a big one in some case.

I can't move the where clause into the CTE as well because the condition depends on the result of another select (e.g. the select from tableA).

Using MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a XML using the first 4 rows for the group. Shred the first three nodes and return `...` for the fourth row.

```sql
with SRC as 
(
    select 'A' grp, 'abc' rec
    union select 'A', 'def'
    union select 'A', 'ghi'
    union select 'A', 'jkl'
    union select 'B', 'mno'
    union select 'B', 'pqr'
)
select (
       select ','+S2.X.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
       from (
            select top(4) S.rec, '...' as eli
            from SRC as S
            where S.grp = tableA.grp
            for xml path('X'), type
            -- order by ?
            ) as S1(X)
         cross apply S1.X.nodes('(X[position() lt 4]/rec, X[position() eq 4]/eli)/text()') as S2(X)
       for xml path(''), type
       ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'nvarchar(max)')
from (select 'A') as tableA(grp);
```

**How does this work?**

The innermost query creates an XML using the first four rows.

```
select top(4) S.rec, '...' as eli
from SRC as S
where S.grp = tableA.grp
for xml path('X'), type
-- order by ?
```

that looks like this

```xml
<X>
  <rec>abc</rec>
  <eli>...</eli>
</X>
<X>
  <rec>def</rec>
  <eli>...</eli>
</X>
<X>
  <rec>ghi</rec>
  <eli>...</eli>
</X>
<X>
  <rec>jkl</rec>
  <eli>...</eli>
</X>
```

The XML is then shredded using `nodes()`

```sql
S1.X.nodes('(X[position() lt 4]/rec, X[position() eq 4]/eli)/text()') as S2(X)
```

`X[position() lt 4]/rec` gives you the `rec` value from the first three `X`nodes and `X[position() eq 4]/eli` gives you the value from `eli` for the fourth row.

The result of the shredded XML as a table.

```
abc
def
ghi
...
```

Then comes a regular XML concatenation using `for xml path` with the little twist that I use `substring(text()[1], 2)` in a `values()` clause to remove the first comma.

**Another way:**

You can use `row_number()` in a case to figure out when the fourth row i returned a. Note that I have add an `order by` clause both to the `row_number()` function and the nested query to make sure what rows are returned.

```sql
with SRC as 
(
    select 'A' grp, 'abc' rec
    union select 'A', 'def'
    union select 'A', 'ghi'
    union select 'A', 'jkl'
    union select 'B', 'mno'
    union select 'B', 'pqr'
)
select (
       select top(4) ','+case when row_number() over(order by S.rec) = 4 then '...' else S.rec end
       from SRC as S
       where S.grp = tableA.grp
       order by S.rec
       for xml path(''), type
       ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'nvarchar(max)')
from (select 'A') as tableA(grp);
```

Comment: Wow, this is eyes popping, this is the work of XML query to accomplish the task, which is kinda alien to me, would be great if you can explain what is going on there?

Comment: @user1589188 Added a bit of an explanation and a also included another way to do it. I think that the second version is faster.

Comment: Ah! Love the second version, although got rid of the where clause, the order by clause managed to sneak in. But still, better than my current version. Picked!

Comment: @user1589188 You could do it without the order by (both of them). But the result (what rows you get) is not guaranteed. Change the order by in `row_number()` to `over(order by 1/0)`.

Comment: What is the effect of having order by clause in the select and have order by 1/0 in the row_number()?

Comment: @user1589188 There is no guarantee that `row_number()` will enumerate the rows in the correct order. I currently don't even know how I would go about to make SQL Server do that but .... without an order by on a unique value you are not guaranteed by SQL Server that the rows will always be numbered in the same way.

Comment: In that case I think I can't have the desire order in select and 1/0 for row_number just to avoid repeating the same order clause.

Comment: @user1589188 there is not performance hit to use the same order by clause in both places. The rows coming out of the query that feeds the row_number function is already sorted and the optimizer knows this and does not add an extra order by step in the queryplan.

Comment: And I can confirm that your `row_number` version is faster than my original `count` version! But `STUFF` is faster than `substring(text()[1], 2)`